# Small business server 2011 standard - applications randomly closing for remote desktop users

Tags: windows, windows-sbs, malware

Small business server 2011 standard - applications randomly closing for remote desktop users

I have an issue where when you are connected through remote desktop (doesn't matter whether you have administrative rights or not).

What happens:

Any application that you run (outlook, word, excel, notepad, cmd etc..) the application will randomly crash and produce an error as such:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 14.0.6112.5000, time stamp: 0x4e9b2b30
Faulting module name: ieframe.dll, version: 8.0.7600.16930, time stamp: 0x4eeb0187
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000131e03
Faulting process id: 0x3d4c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cecf3491388e43
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll
Report Id: 1c06abd4-3b2b-11e3-bd8d-001999b270e9
```

I noticed the ieframe.dll, but its not constant for every application that crashes, e.g.:

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 14.0.6109.5005, time stamp: 0x4e79b6c0
Faulting module name: PSTOREC.DLL_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4a5be02a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000007fef39c7158
Faulting process id: 0x43f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cecf33fe5eec26
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: PSTOREC.DLL
Report Id: 0c0f5934-3b2b-11e3-bd8d-001999b270e9
```

I am unable to perform a sfc /scannow command due to the cmd.exe crashing as well..

I have performed a virus scan on the server which did originally pick up 5 viruses:

```
riskware.tool.ck -> File
riskware.tool.ck - > Memory Process
trojan.agent.bdavgen -> File
trojan.agent -> File
HiJack.comsysapp -> Registry Data
```

But after removing these and rebooting the machine we have had no luck

Has anyone else ever come across this issue before? Also to elaborate it is happening as frequently as every minute.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is either more malware on your system that is not being detected, or the malware that you removed has already done significant damage to your system. I'd be restoring from backup ASAP if I were you.